# Sql 2008 geometry type and fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, geometry, spatial

I have to use spatial index to search defined area on the map. I'm having difficulties with mapping sql geometry type using c# classes and fluent nhibernate. There are some posts about this topic but nothing that helped me. Can someone please explain me the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Could you elaborate the actual issue / post some code and what you were trying to do? You can map your properties using the `NHibernate.Spatial.Type.GeometryType` which is included in [NHibernate.Spatial](http://nhforge.org/wikis/spatial/default.aspx) extension. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495169/nhibernate-spatial-and-sql-2008-geography-type-how-to-configure) similar question could help too.