# NH spatial and Fluent Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have read this in order to compile NH spatial for Nhibernate 3.1

http://build-failed.blogspot.it/2012/02/nhibernate-spatial-part-2.html

I have also read this

[NHibernate.Spatial and Sql 2008 Geography type - How to configure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495169/nhibernate-spatial-and-sql-2008-geography-type-how-to-configure)

but the same code for me don't compile... I have this

```
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
    namespace Core
    {
        public class District
        {
            public virtual int Id { get; set; }
            public virtual Polygon Area { get; set; }
            public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }

    using Core;
    using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

    namespace TestNHSpatial
    {
        public class DistrictMap : ClassMap<District>
        {
            public DistrictMap()
            {
                ImportType<NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point>();

                Id(x => x.Id);
                Map(x => x.Name);
                Map(x => x.Area).CustomType<Wgs84GeographyType>();
            }
        }
    }
```

and this

```
[Serializable]
public class Wgs84GeographyType : MsSql2008GeographyType
{
    protected override void SetDefaultSRID(GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry geometry)
    {
        geometry.SRID = 4326;
    }
}
```

finally

```
var cfg = new OrderingSystemConfiguration();

var configuration = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
    .ConnectionString(connString)
    .Dialect<MsSql2008GeographyDialect>())
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(
        AutoMap.AssemblyOf<District>(cfg)))
    .BuildConfiguration();

var exporter = new SchemaExport(configuration);

exporter.Drop(false, true);

exporter.Create(true, true);
```

i have this error...

NHibernate.MappingException : An association from the table District refers to an unmapped class: NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Polygon

can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: its pretty specific, its saying it cant map polygon class - either provide mapping for polygon or tell fluent to ignore it

Comment: something like Map(a => a.Area).CustomType(typeof(NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Polygon));

Comment: i have already Map(x => x.Area).CustomType<Wgs84GeographyType>(); don't compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE:

The code has some issues, namely:

- You're using AutoMappings. You need to use custom mappings
- You're using the wrong assembly when searching for the mappings
- The export schema code is incorrect.

---

I'm the author of the blog post that you refer.

Change the type from Polygon (from NetTopologySuite) to IPolygon(from GeoAPI).

Should be something like this:

```
using GeoAPI.Geometries;

public class District
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IPolygon Area { get; set; }        

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Anyway, if this doesn't work, send me a zip with a test project and I'll check it out.

Comment: as Pedro suggest me... this is wrong .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<District>(cfg))) and This is correct .Mappings(m => .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<DistrictMap>()) then ... i'musing a SchemaExport instruction to generate the database schema and I need something additional on the mappings to have that working correctly .. I You have to put a:.CustomSqlType("GEOGRAPHY"); on the fluentNHibernate mappings. Now work fine Thank you very much!!!